# Не отображается svg в браузере

Tags: svg, svg-animation, inkscape

Сделал картинку в Inkscape. Для того, чтобы сделать анимацию рукописного ввода. Пытаюсь вставить на сайт, но она не отображается.
Пытался просто код вставлять `<code lang="html"> <svg>...</svg> </code>`, и через `img`, ни так, ни так не выходит. Ошибок в консоли нет.

Вот код [картинки](https://codepen.io/gumarov1991/pen/XWrLqQO).

```
<svg width="11in" height="2in" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
        <defs>
            <clipPath id="clipPath6041">
                <g transform="matrix(.26458 0 0 .26458 -2.0375 6.5372)" aria-label="Alvert and Viktoriya">
                    <path d="m708.06 211.75q-1.2 0-2.4-0.26666-6.4-1.2-6.4-11.333 0-16.4 16.533-55.867 6.4-14.933 9.4667-29.067 1.2-5.4667 1.2-8.6667 0-3.3333-0.26667-5.2-0.66666-5.8667-4.4-8.1333-6.6667-3.6-14.933-3.6-8.6667 0-18.267 4.2667-9.6 4.2667-18.133 10.4-8.4 6.1333-15.333 14.667-6.9333 8.4-10.4 17.733-3.3333 9.2-3.3333 16.667 0 3.0667 0.53333 5.8667 2.1333 9.2 8 13.733 5.8667 4.5333 13.867 4.5333 11.2 0 20.933-9.8667 9.8667-9.8667 9.8667-20.933 0-6-2.4-8.6667-2.4-2.6667-4.9333-2.6667t-5.0667 0.8q-2.5333 0.66666-2.5333-0.13334 0-0.93333 3.0667-2.2667 3.0667-1.4667 6.4-1.4667 3.3333 0 6.1333 2 5.2 4 5.2 12.133 0 8.1333-6.2667 16.4-6.1333 8.1333-15.2 13.2-9.0667 4.9333-18 4.9333-8.8 0-16.4-6.4-7.6-6.5333-10.133-17.467-0.66666-3.2-0.66666-6.8 0-8.4 4.1333-18.267 4.1333-9.8667 11.867-18.267 7.8667-8.5333 16.933-14.133 9.0667-5.7333 19.2-9.4667 10.133-3.8667 19.067-3.8667 8.9333 0 16.267 2.8 12.933 5.6 12.933 23.733 0 13.333-9.6 33.067-6 12.267-10.667 26.4-6.9333 20.933-6.9333 29.067 0 6.1333 4.1333 6.1333 8.2667 0 28.933-21.467 14.533-15.067 22.8-33.067 5.3333-11.467 5.3333-21.067 0-5.0667-0.8-7.0667-0.8-2.1333-1.0667-2.6667-0.26666-0.66667-1.0667-1.0667-0.8-0.53333-1.0667-0.53333-1.8667-0.53334-3.8667-0.8-2-0.4-2.4-1.8667-0.26666-1.4667 1.4667-1.7333l2.5333 0.26666q6.1333 1.7333 10.667 8.6667 2.5333 3.8667 2.5333 9.3333 0 5.3333-2.5333 12.667-6.1333 16.267-18.933 32.133-12.8 15.733-25.333 24.133-12.4 8.4-20.267 8.4z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m790.67 147.08q-1.8667 1.6-4.1333 1.6-2.2667 0-3.6-1.6-1.3333-1.6-1.0667-3.8667 0.4-2.2667 2.2667-3.8667 1.8667-1.6 4.1333-1.6 2.2667 0 3.6 1.6 1.4667 1.6 1.0667 3.8667-0.4 2.2667-2.2667 3.8667zm-13.067 48.933q2.5333 0 5.3333-2.5333 4.9333-4.9333 12.533-20.133 0.93334-2 1.8667-1.2 0.26667 0.26666 0.26667 0.93333 0 0.53333-1.0667 2.9333-1.0667 2.2667-2 4.1333-0.8 1.8667-3.3333 6.1333-2.4 4.1333-4.4 6.4-5.4667 6.2667-10.4 6.2667-4.8 0-6.9333-2.9333-2.1333-2.9333-2.1333-6.5333t1.7333-7.8667l8.5333-21.733q0.26667-0.8 0.26667-2.1333 0-1.3333-1.6-3.4667l7.3333-0.13333q3.0667 0 3.6 1.2 0.53333 1.0667-0.8 3.4667l-10.667 24.933q-2.2667 4.9333-2.2667 8.4 0 3.8667 4.1333 3.8667z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m829.98 162.95q0-3.6-3.6-3.6-5.3333 0-12.4 6.1333-6.9333 6-11.6 12.667-2 3.8667-3.3333 9.7333-1.2 5.8667-1.2 8.1333 0 2.2667 0.8 2.9333h-8.4q-2 0-1.0667-3.4667 1.0667-3.6 2.8-7.7333 1.7333-4.1333 4.2667-9.4667 2.6667-5.4667 3.8667-8.2667-10.933 20.667-14.133 23.733-1.3333 1.2-1.3333-0.8 0-0.4 0.26667-0.93334 4.6667-6.1333 18.533-33.333 14-27.2 19.6-35.6 4.5333-6.5333 8.8-6.5333 0 0 0.13333 0h0.66667q0.13333 0 2.2667 0.4 2.2667 0.4 3.3333 0.13333-4.9333 3.7333-13.6 17.2-8.6667 13.333-13.733 23.467-5.0667 10-6.8 15.2 12.133-15.067 21.733-18.667 4.5333-1.4667 7.2-1.4667 5.8667 0 5.8667 4.9333 0 1.6-0.66666 3.6-1.8667 5.0667-7.7333 9.2-5.7333 4-12.667 4.6667-1.6 3.7333-1.6 6.9333 0 3.0667 0.66666 5.6 1.6 6.4 6 7.8667 0.93334 0.26667 1.8667 0.26667 3.7333 0 8.8-4.6667 4.1333-4.5333 10.8-18.267 0.93333-1.7333 1.4667-1.0667 0.53333 0.53333 0.53333 1.0667 0 0.53333-2 5.2-2 4.6667-5.6 10.267-7.6 11.467-16.8 11.467-5.6 0-8.6667-3.2-4.4-4.5333-4.4-11.867 0-3.7333 2-7.6 2-3.8667 4.6667-4.1333 0.4 0 0.8 0 4.6667 0 9.0667-3.6 4.5333-3.6 4.5333-6.5333z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m840.69 188.28q0-11.067 10.667-37.067h-6.9333q-0.66666 0-0.93333-0.66666-0.13333-0.8 0.13333-1.4667 0.4-0.8 1.0667-0.8h8q4.8-10.533 8.9333-17.6t7.6-9.4667q3.4667-2.5333 4.9333-2.5333 1.6 0 2.2667 0.26667 3.0667 1.4667 3.0667 6.1333 0 4.5333-3.0667 11.067-3.0667 6.5333-6 12.133h6.4q0.66667 0 0.8 0.8 0.26667 0.66667-0.13333 1.4667-0.26667 0.66666-0.93334 0.66666h-7.7333q-7.3333 12.4-17.733 22l-3.0667 13.6q-0.4 1.7333-0.4 3.4667 0 1.6 0.93334 3.3333 0.93333 1.7333 2.9333 1.7333 2.2667 0 5.0667-1.6 6.4-4.8 14.133-20.133 0.53333-1.2 1.2-1.4667 0.8-0.26667 0.93333 0.4 0.13333 0.53333-0.4 1.8667-4.4 9.2-6.9333 13.067-7.2 11.6-15.333 11.6-4.1333 0-6.8-3.0667-2.6667-3.0667-2.6667-7.7333zm26.8-40q8.8-15.733 8.8-21.867 0-2.6667-0.93334-2.6667-1.4667 0-4.5333 4.2667-2.9333 4.2667-10 20.267zm-1.7333 2.9333h-6.2667q-1.6 3.7333-7.2 17.733 7.2-7.4667 13.467-17.733z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m894.85 152.28q9.7333 0 9.7333 12.267 0 5.6-2.9333 12-3.7333 8.6667-11.2 15.733 1.7333 3.3333 6.2667 3.3333 3.6 0 6.8-3.6 4-4.1333 5.7333-7.2 1.7333-3.2 2.5333-4.6667 0.8-1.4667 2-4.1333 1.3333-2.8 1.6-3.3333 0.26667-0.66667 0.93333-0.66667 1.3333-0.13333 1.3333 0.93334 0 0.4-0.26667 0.93333l-0.8 1.8667q-0.8 1.8667-1.2 2.6667t-1.4667 2.9333q-0.93333 2-1.7333 3.2-0.66667 1.2-2 3.2-1.2 2-2.2667 3.2-0.93333 1.2-2.4 2.6667-1.4667 1.4667-2.8 2.2667-3.3333 2-6.2667 2-5.4667 0-8.5333-3.4667-6.1333 4.5333-11.333 4.5333-9.7333 0-9.7333-12.267 0-5.6 2.9333-12 4-9.3333 11.2-15.867 7.3333-6.5333 13.867-6.5333zm1.4667 4.1333q-3.6 0-8.5333 4.8t-8.8 13.067q-4.6667 9.6-4.6667 15.733t4.6667 6.1333q3.3333 0 7.4667-3.6-2.1333-3.0667-2.1333-6.5333 0.26667-5.7333 4.6667-5.7333 1.7333 0 2.8 1.2 1.2 1.2 1.2 2.2667 0 0.93333-0.26667 2 2.2667-3.3333 5.2-9.4667 3.3333-6.8 3.3333-13.333 0-6.5333-4.9333-6.5333z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m933.37 145.48q0 6-7.6 11.333 2.6667 0.13334 7.0667 0.13334 4.5333 0 11.333-0.66667 0.26666 0.4 0.26666 2.1333 0 1.7333-1.6 5.2-1.6 3.3333-2.9333 5.8667-1.2 2.4-2.4 4.6667-1.0667 2.1333-2.5333 5.3333-1.3333 3.2-2.2667 5.8667-3.3333 10.133 1.0667 10.133 5.6 0 16.533-22.267 0.93333-1.7333 1.4667-1.3333 0.66666 0.4 0.66666 1.0667 0 0.53333-1.7333 4.1333-1.7333 3.4667-3.7333 7.2t-6.2667 8.6667q-5.0667 6.1333-9.7333 6.1333-5.2 0-7.2-6.2667-0.4-1.2-0.4-3.6t1.4667-6.4q1.6-4 4.9333-9.7333t3.7333-6.6667q0.4-1.0667 0.4-2 0-4.1333-10.667-4.4l-1.6 4.2667q-8.4 22-16.133 29.467-1.3333 1.2-1.3333-0.8 0-0.4 0.26667-0.93334 7.4667-9.8667 12.933-23.333t7.6-25.6q0.8-4.1333 3.7333-4.1333t4.2667 3.7333q0.4 1.2 0.4 2.8z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m968.28 147.08q-1.8667 1.6-4.1333 1.6-2.2667 0-3.6-1.6-1.3333-1.6-1.0667-3.8667 0.4-2.2667 2.2667-3.8667 1.8667-1.6 4.1333-1.6t3.6 1.6q1.4667 1.6 1.0667 3.8667-0.4 2.2667-2.2667 3.8667zm-13.067 48.933q2.5333 0 5.3333-2.5333 4.9333-4.9333 12.533-20.133 0.93333-2 1.8667-1.2 0.26666 0.26666 0.26666 0.93333 0 0.53333-1.0667 2.9333-1.0667 2.2667-2 4.1333-0.8 1.8667-3.3333 6.1333-2.4 4.1333-4.4 6.4-5.4667 6.2667-10.4 6.2667-4.8 0-6.9333-2.9333t-2.1333-6.5333 1.7333-7.8667l8.5333-21.733q0.26667-0.8 0.26667-2.1333 0-1.3333-1.6-3.4667l7.3333-0.13333q3.0667 0 3.6 1.2 0.53334 1.0667-0.8 3.4667l-10.667 24.933q-2.2667 4.9333-2.2667 8.4 0 3.8667 4.1333 3.8667z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m954.79 241.08q-5.8667 0-9.0667-2.5333-3.2-2.4-3.2-5.8667 0-3.4667 2-7.8667 3.4667-6.8 12.533-10.933 6.8-3.2 18-6 11.2-2.6667 14.4-3.6 4.8-8.4 11.467-30-7.7334 13.6-12.933 19.067-5.2 5.4667-10.533 5.4667-7.2 0-8.4-6-0.53334-0.93333-0.26667-2.8 0.26667-1.8667 0.26667-2.6667 0.13333-0.8 0.93333-2.5333 0.8-1.8667 1.0667-2.6667 1.4667-3.0667 2.5333-4.8-2.1333 0-1.2-2.1333l2.4-4.6667q4.5333-8.6667 7.4667-14.667 1.3333-2.8 5.2-2.8h8.1333q-0.26667 0.26667-1.3333 1.0667-2.4 1.6-3.6 3.7333-4.8 8.2667-12 23.6-2.9333 6.2667-2.9333 9.2t0.93334 4.1333q1.0667 1.2 2.8 1.2 2.5333 0 7.0667-5.3333 9.4667-11.067 20.933-34.8 1.4667-2.8 5.2-2.8h7.2q-3.4667 2.4-5.4667 6.1333-2 3.6-4.4 9.8667-2.2666 6.2667-5.8666 16.667-3.4667 10.4-5.3334 15.6 12.533-3.7333 19.2-13.2 2.9334-4.1333 8.4-14.667 0.9334-1.8667 1.6-1.4667 0.8 0.4 0.8 1.0667t-2.2666 5.2q-2.1334 4.4-4.4 8.2667-2.2667 3.7333-5.8667 7.7333t-8 6.2667q-4.4 2.4-11.733 5.0667-10.267 18.667-20.667 27.467-9.7333 8-21.067 8zm-7.7333-13.2q-1.4667 2.9333-1.4667 5.3333 0 2.5333 1.8667 3.8667 1.8667 1.3333 4.6667 1.3333 7.7333 0 16.533-8 8.8-7.8667 15.467-16.933l2.9333-4.9333q-22 5.7333-27.733 8.2667-8.5333 3.7333-12.267 11.067z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                    <path d="m1066.8 162.82q-2.4 2.4-6.8 10.933-4.4 8.4-5.3334 12.667-0.8 4.1333-0.8 6.8 0 2.5333 2 2.5333 2.5334 0 6.2667-4.6667 5.4667-6.8 10.8-17.733 0.5333-1.2 1.2-1.3333 1.0667-0.4 1.0667 0.8 0 0.66667-0.4 1.6-12.267 24.8-20.667 24.8-3.8667 0-6.2667-3.7333-1.2-2-1.2-5.3333 0-3.3333 1.3334-8.1333-10.667 17.2-18.4 17.2-2.1334 0-3.8667-1.3333-4-2.8-4-9.6 0-13.067 11.333-26.533 6.4-7.4667 15.733-9.7333 2.5333-0.66666 4.8-0.66666 6.1333 0 10.4 4.2667 1.3333 1.4667 0.8 2.8-0.5334 1.3333-2.2667 1.0667-1.4667-4.8-6.4-4.8-5.7333 0-14.133 9.0667-4.8 5.3333-8.9334 12.533-5.2 8.6667-5.2 13.867t3.3334 5.2q8 0 20.933-24.533 2.5333-4.9333 4.2667-6.6667 1.7333-1.8667 4.4-1.8667 0.5333 0 2.6666 0.4 2.2667 0.4 3.3334 0.13333z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".37795"/>
                </g>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clipPath6071">
                <g fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1" aria-label="Albert">
                    <path d="m37.37 40.727q0.97367 0 0.97367 1.2277 0 1.3123-1.0583 2.4553-1.8627 2.0743-3.429 5.207-2.3707 4.7413-2.3707 8.5513 0 1.4817 0.508 2.159 0.55033 0.67733 1.2277 0.67733 2.032 0 4.7413-3.302 2.413-3.0903 3.683-6.0113 0.33867-0.67733 0.67733-0.59267 0.33867 0.08467 0.04233 0.762-1.7357 3.8523-3.937 6.7733-1.143 1.5663-2.8363 2.5823-1.6933 1.0583-3.3867 1.0583-1.651 0-2.4977-1.3547-0.84667-1.3123-0.84667-3.1327 0-1.8203 0.42333-3.5983 0.46567-1.778 1.1853-2.7517-4.2757 5.1223-9.1017 8.2127-2.54 1.5663-5.6303 1.8627-0.29633 0.04233-1.016 0.04233-0.67733 0-1.651-0.508-3.048-1.27-3.048-6.1807 0-4.953 3.2173-10.71 1.6933-3.048 3.7253-5.3763-2.8363-1.3547-4.2333-2.921-1.016-1.143-1.016-2.7517 0-1.6087 0.635-2.032 0.42333-0.55033 0.762-0.21167 0.254 0.381 0 0.93133-0.21167 0.55033-0.21167 1.0583 0 1.143 1.2277 2.54 1.2277 1.397 3.5983 2.4977 9.9483-11.049 20.659-11.049 3.3443 0 5.2917 1.524 1.9897 1.4817 1.9897 3.8523 0 2.5823-2.8787 4.9953-1.4393 1.27-4.1063 2.2013-4.064 1.4393-9.6943 1.4393-5.588 0-9.271-1.1853-4.2757 6.0537-5.8843 10.075-1.6087 3.9793-1.6087 6.1807 0 0.46567 0.04233 0.84667 0.508 3.5137 3.556 3.5137 3.429 0 7.9587-3.7253 3.2173-2.7093 6.3077-6.4347 3.0903-3.7253 4.572-6.5617 1.524-2.8363 2.7093-2.8363zm6.5617-9.017q0-1.8203-1.524-2.794-1.4817-0.97367-4.1063-0.97367-2.6247 0-5.2493 0.84667-2.5823 0.84667-4.8683 2.4977-2.2437 1.651-4.0217 3.3867-1.7357 1.7357-3.7677 4.1487 3.175 1.016 7.7893 1.016 8.6783 0 12.658-2.794 3.0903-2.159 3.0903-5.334z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m44.181 51.395q-0.04233 0.16933-0.381 1.1853-0.33867 0.97367-0.59267 1.905-0.21167 0.889-0.21167 1.8203 0 0.889 0.42333 1.6933 0.42333 0.762 1.3547 0.762 1.524 0 2.9633-2.032 1.4393-2.0743 3.048-5.2493 0.33867-0.59267 0.635-0.46567 0.21167 0.16933 0.08467 0.46567-0.127 0.254-0.55033 1.1853-0.381 0.889-0.59267 1.27-0.16933 0.33867-0.67733 1.27-0.46567 0.889-0.84667 1.3547-0.33867 0.42333-0.97367 1.143-0.59267 0.67733-1.143 1.016-1.4817 0.93133-2.794 0.93133-1.3123 0-2.032-0.55033-0.71967-0.59267-0.889-1.2277-0.127-0.67733-0.127-1.1853t0.04233-1.3123q0.127-1.3547 0.508-2.6247 0.42333-1.27 0.46567-1.4393 0.97367-3.5137 2.7517-7.6623 1.8203-4.1487 3.048-6.223 1.27-2.1167 1.9897-2.8787 1.4393-1.524 2.8363-1.524 0.97367 0 1.3123 1.397 0.04233 0.254 0.04233 0.635 0 1.4393-1.016 3.6407-3.6407 8.0857-8.6783 12.7zm0.33867-1.3547q2.159-2.2013 4.2757-5.5457 2.1167-3.3443 3.0903-5.6727 1.016-2.3707 1.016-3.2173 0-0.84667-0.29633-0.84667-0.42333 0-1.6087 1.6933-1.1853 1.651-3.2173 6.0113-1.9897 4.318-3.2597 7.5777z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m61.533 48.051q0-2.413-1.9897-2.413-0.16933 0-0.33867 0-0.762 0.08467-0.889-0.29633-0.127-0.381 0.381-0.508t1.1007-0.04233q2.2013 0.33867 3.0057 2.0743 0.55033 1.0583 0.55033 2.0743 0 3.6407-2.667 7.1543-2.667 3.556-6.9003 3.556-1.5663 0-2.54-0.889-0.97367-0.889-0.97367-2.3707 0-1.778 2.032-6.0113-3.4713 6.5617-4.4873 7.5353-0.42333 0.381-0.42333-0.254 0-0.127 0.08467-0.29633 1.4817-1.9473 5.8843-10.583 4.445-8.636 6.223-11.303 1.4393-2.0743 2.794-2.0743 0 0 0.04233 0h0.21167q0.04233 0 0.71967 0.127 0.71967 0.127 1.0583 0.04233-1.397 1.4817-4.4027 5.9267-7.4507 11.049-7.4507 16.51 0 2.2437 1.4393 2.54 0.127 0.04233 0.29633 0.04233 1.3123 0 3.2597-2.3283 1.9897-2.3707 3.2597-5.3763 0.71967-1.5663 0.71967-2.8363z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m67.362 53.046q-0.59267 1.4393-0.59267 3.2173 0 1.1853 0.508 1.905 0.55033 0.67733 1.524 0.67733 3.8523 0 6.985-7.239 0.29633-0.67733 0.71967-0.59267 0.16933 0.04233 0.16933 0.21167 0 0.16933-0.97367 2.2437-0.93133 2.032-1.905 3.302-2.159 2.9633-5.334 2.9633-1.6933 0-2.8787-1.1007-1.1853-1.1007-1.1853-3.0057t0.889-4.0217q0.93133-2.159 2.4977-3.9793 1.5663-1.8627 3.5983-2.7093 0.97367-0.42333 1.8627-0.42333t1.651 0.508q0.71967 0.59267 0.71967 1.3123 0 2.54-3.048 4.8683-0.93133 0.71967-2.6247 1.3123-1.6933 0.55033-2.5823 0.55033zm7.112-6.7733q0-0.84667-0.67733-0.84667-1.1853 0-3.5983 2.921-1.4393 1.778-2.54 3.9793 0.71967 0 2.0743-0.508 1.397-0.508 2.413-1.3547 2.3283-1.9897 2.3283-4.191z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m81.633 42.59q0 1.905-2.413 3.5983 0.84667 0.04233 2.2437 0.04233 1.4393 0 3.5983-0.21167 0.08467 0.127 0.08467 0.67733 0 0.55033-0.508 1.651-0.508 1.0583-0.93133 1.8627-0.381 0.762-0.762 1.4817-0.33867 0.67733-0.80433 1.6933-0.42333 1.016-0.71967 1.8627-1.0583 3.2173 0.33867 3.2173 1.778 0 5.2493-7.0697 0.29633-0.55033 0.46567-0.42333 0.21167 0.127 0.21167 0.33867 0 0.16933-0.55033 1.3123-0.55033 1.1007-1.1853 2.286-0.635 1.1853-1.9897 2.7517-1.6087 1.9473-3.0903 1.9473-1.651 0-2.286-1.9897-0.127-0.381-0.127-1.143t0.46567-2.032q0.508-1.27 1.5663-3.0903 1.0583-1.8203 1.1853-2.1167 0.127-0.33867 0.127-0.635 0-1.3123-3.3867-1.397l-0.508 1.3547q-2.667 6.985-5.1223 9.3557-0.42333 0.381-0.42333-0.254 0-0.127 0.08467-0.29633 2.3707-3.1327 4.1063-7.4083 1.7357-4.2757 2.413-8.128 0.254-1.3123 1.1853-1.3123 0.93133 0 1.3547 1.1853 0.127 0.381 0.127 0.889z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m85.856 56.179q0-3.5137 3.3867-11.769h-2.2013q-0.21167 0-0.29633-0.21167-0.04233-0.254 0.04233-0.46567 0.127-0.254 0.33867-0.254h2.54q1.524-3.3443 2.8363-5.588 1.3123-2.2437 2.413-3.0057 1.1007-0.80433 1.5663-0.80433 0.508 0 0.71967 0.08467 0.97367 0.46567 0.97367 1.9473 0 1.4393-0.97367 3.5137-0.97367 2.0743-1.905 3.8523h2.032q0.21167 0 0.254 0.254 0.08467 0.21167-0.04233 0.46567-0.08467 0.21167-0.29633 0.21167h-2.4553q-2.3283 3.937-5.6303 6.985l-0.97367 4.318q-0.127 0.55033-0.127 1.1007 0 0.508 0.29633 1.0583t0.93133 0.55033q0.71967 0 1.6087-0.508 2.032-1.524 4.4873-6.3923 0.16933-0.381 0.381-0.46567 0.254-0.08467 0.29633 0.127 0.04233 0.16933-0.127 0.59267-1.397 2.921-2.2013 4.1487-2.286 3.683-4.8683 3.683-1.3123 0-2.159-0.97367t-0.84667-2.4553zm8.509-12.7q2.794-4.9953 2.794-6.9427 0-0.84667-0.29633-0.84667-0.46567 0-1.4393 1.3547-0.93133 1.3547-3.175 6.4347zm-0.55033 0.93133h-1.9897q-0.508 1.1853-2.286 5.6303 2.286-2.3707 4.2757-5.6303z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                </g>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="clipPath6089">
                <g transform="translate(-7.1584 1.6135)">
                    <path d="m120.7 47.913q-0.8255 0.8255-2.3389 3.7606-1.5134 2.8892-1.8344 4.3568-0.27517 1.4217-0.27517 2.3389 0 0.87136 0.68792 0.87136 0.87136 0 2.1555-1.6051 1.8803-2.3389 3.7148-6.0995 0.18345-0.41275 0.41275-0.45861 0.36689-0.13758 0.36689 0.27517 0 0.22931-0.13758 0.55033-4.2192 8.5302-7.1085 8.5302-1.33 0-2.1555-1.2841-0.41275-0.68792-0.41275-1.8344 0-1.1465 0.45861-2.7975-3.6689 5.9161-6.3288 5.9161-0.73378 0-1.33-0.45861-1.3758-0.96308-1.3758-3.302 0-4.4944 3.8982-9.1264 2.2013-2.5682 5.4116-3.3479 0.87136-0.2293 1.651-0.2293 2.1096 0 3.5772 1.4676 0.45861 0.50447 0.27516 0.96308-0.18344 0.45861-0.77963 0.36689-0.50448-1.651-2.2013-1.651-1.972 0-4.8613 3.1186-1.651 1.8344-3.0727 4.3109-1.7886 2.981-1.7886 4.7696t1.1465 1.7886q2.7517 0 7.2002-8.4384 0.87136-1.6969 1.4676-2.2931 0.5962-0.64206 1.5134-0.64206 0.18345 0 0.91722 0.13758 0.77964 0.13758 1.1465 0.04586z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m136.64 45.299q-5.6409 9.906-5.6409 12.933 0 1.1924 0.87136 1.1924 2.3389 0 6.283-7.934 0.27517-0.64205 0.55034-0.50447 0.27516 0.13758 0.27516 0.36689 0 0.22931-0.18344 0.55033-2.4306 4.9071-4.1275 6.7874-1.651 1.8344-3.3479 1.8344-1.651 0-2.5224-1.2841-0.45862-0.59619-0.45862-1.6051 0-1.0548 0.45862-2.5224 0.45861-1.4676 2.5224-4.7696 0.50447-0.8255 0.50447-1.2841 0-0.50447-0.77964-0.50447t-2.981 2.0638q-3.302 3.0268-6.3747 9.0805-0.27516 0.45861-0.64205 0.59619-0.32103 0.09172-1.33 0.13758-1.009 0.04586-1.33 0.22931 0.73378-1.4676 2.8892-6.0078 3.8523-8.0257 5.0447-9.1722 0.55033-0.55033 1.5134-0.55033 0.18345 0 0.91722 0.13758 0.77964 0.13758 1.1465 0.04586-1.6969 0.91722-5.5492 8.6219 2.1555-2.6599 3.8982-4.2192 1.7886-1.6051 4.2651-2.9351 2.4765-1.3758 3.623-1.3758 0.27517 0 0.50448 0.09172z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                    <path d="m147.87 57.681q0 1.4676 1.1924 1.4676 2.1555 0 5.7326-7.2002 0.13758-0.27517 0.2293-0.55033 0.13759-0.27517 0.36689-0.36689 0.27517-0.09172 0.36689 0.13758 0.0917 0.18344-0.0917 0.64206-3.6689 8.5302-7.4295 8.5302-1.2382 0-1.972-1.1007-0.73378-1.1007-0.73378-2.1555 0-1.1007 0.22931-2.0179-2.66 4.4027-4.5861 4.9989-0.55034 0.22931-1.1007 0.22931-0.50447 0-1.0089-0.13758-2.2472-0.59619-2.2472-3.5772 0-2.0179 1.009-4.4485 1.0548-2.4765 2.9351-4.7237 1.8803-2.2472 4.5402-3.0268 0.96308-0.32103 2.2472-0.32103 1.33 0 2.9351 0.8255 3.1186-5.8702 5.3199-10.869 0.64206-1.5134 1.2382-1.9262 0.64206-0.45861 1.1465-0.45861 0.55033 0 0.64206 0 0.13758 0 0.87136 0.13758 0.77963 0.09172 1.1924 0.04586-1.0548 0.96308-5.595 9.3557-5.7785 10.732-6.9709 14.309-0.45861 1.33-0.45861 2.2013zm2.2472-12.061q-0.59619-0.5962-1.6969-0.5962-1.0548 0-2.981 1.6051-3.0727 2.5682-5.0906 6.3288-1.33 2.4765-1.33 4.0816 0 0.73378 0.27516 1.33 0.32103 0.5962 0.96309 0.5962 1.5593 0 3.8523-3.2103 2.293-3.2103 6.0078-10.135z" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".1"/>
                </g>
            </clipPath>
        </defs>
        <metadata>
            <rdf:RDF>
                <cc:Work rdf:about="">
                    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
                    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
                    <dc:title/>
                </cc:Work>
            </rdf:RDF>
        </metadata>
        <g transform="translate(0,-159.2)">
            <g>
                <g transform="translate(-9.525 137.05)" clip-path="url(#clipPath6041)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="13">
                    <g transform="translate(6.8969 .3034)">
                        <path d="m170.13 42.418 3.4018-0.85045 1.9844 1.7009v3.0238l-1.7954 3.8743-4.1577 3.0238-4.4412 0.66146-3.7798-2.5513-1.9844-5.9531 2.1734-6.1421 6.6146-5.9531 6.7091-3.4018 4.3467-0.37798 2.2679 0.66146 1.7954 1.2284 1.0394 1.8899-0.56697 5.5751-1.8899 6.4256-2.3624 5.9531-1.8899 5.6696-0.56696 3.5908 1.0938 1.2084 2.2718-0.30068 2.8732-1.5702 5.6127-4.9111 3.0736-4.8443 2.1048-3.4077 1.3364-3.4745-0.13364-3.2741-1.3029-1.8542-2.8564-0.81851"/>
                        <path d="m197.91 46.623-2.6458 8.7879 0.0472 2.7403 1.2842 0.26614 1.7205-0.41761 1.1693-1.5702 1.7874-2.9567 1.2946-2.3136 8.9025-14.553"/>
                        <path d="m199.32 43.505-0.42522 1.3702-0.0945 0.28348"/>
                        <path d="m203.62 49.222-2.6931 10.064"/>
                        <path d="m202.35 52.954 1.4886-0.92149 2.5511-2.1732s2.5277-1.819 2.6222-1.8663c0.0945-0.04725 2.6222-0.42522 2.6222-0.42522l0.3071 1.8663s-1.6773 1.7954-1.8662 1.8899c-0.18899 0.0945-2.1025 0.92132-2.1025 0.92132l-1.6064 1.0394-0.44885 2.5986 1.0867 1.7954 1.5355 0.82682 2.1261-0.37798 1.9371-2.0789 4.3878-5.1483 3.0736-3.6248 0.68488-1.4533 2.088-3.9422 0.63477-2.823-0.71829-0.86863-1.921 1.1693-1.019 1.7707-2.2217 4.3932-1.637 4.5269-0.63476 3.3576-0.68571 3.8475 0.94495 1.1576 1.8662-0.14174 1.7245-1.6064 2.2442-3.5435"/>
                        <path d="m214.29 45.718h8.9958"/>
                        <path d="m221.41 53.12 4.9846-5.5043 1.7245-0.42523 1.4883 0.66146 0.54334 2.5041-1.5592 3.8743-1.7718 2.1497-1.819 1.6536-2.7403 0.56696-1.0394-2.3387 0.18898-3.1419"/>
                        <path d="m225.83 54.561 0.77958 3.1183 1.1339 0.66146 1.9608-0.33073 1.1339-1.3229 2.1497-3.0238 0.90951-2.0789 3.4136-8.5517"/>
                        <path d="m235.41 48.011 4.4434 0.43431-0.63476 2.4889-2.7896 5.2285 0.24074 1.9417 1.0867 0.35435 0.8977-0.33073 2.7167-2.8584 3.0474-5.268 1.0867-3.26"/>
                        <path d="m241.37 55.269 1.0631 2.5986 1.3111 0.63783 1.6418-0.61421 1.2639-1.6536 6.5328-9.8642"/>
                        <path d="m248.68 53.197-0.0994 3.9344 0.4009 1.1693 1.4032 0.23386 1.5702-0.93544 7.7174-11.058"/>
                        <path d="m255.91 52.385-0.21534 4.3783-2.0045 4.1761-4.8777 6.0804-2.372 1.9711-0.90203 0.4009-2.4054 0.23386-1.8041-0.4009-0.43432-1.2361 0.3675-2.0379 1.5702-1.7038 4.4434-2.0045 5.3955-1.4533 3.8921-1.2194 2.7197-1.6786 2.9057-3.8034 3.9688-5.1972 2.197-1.5828 1.7718-0.63783 1.2993 0.23623 0.94496 1.0631 0.47247 0.59059"/>
                        <path d="m262.47 53.899-0.14173 3.7561 1.63 0.85045 1.8663-1.0631 6.4728-8.3863"/>
                        <path d="m269.23 53.427 0.18897 3.8034 0.18899 1.2284 1.5355-0.14174 1.8426-2.0316 2.7403-4.7956"/>
                    </g>
                    <path d="m253.64 43.491-0.96885 2.0713"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(0,-159.2)">
            <g>
                <g transform="translate(1.304 134.36)" clip-path="url(#clipPath6089)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="13">
                    <path d="m112.83 48.564-0.94494-1.8663-2.8584-0.89769-4.9341 2.4916-3.9422 6.6149-0.86863 4.4768 1.5368 2.0045 1.2629-0.42152 2.1734-1.5828 3.1892-4.016 5.1027-6.213"/>
                    <path d="m107.26 55.241 1.1225 2.1113 0.23623 3.3073 1.0867 0.61421 1.5592-0.66146 10.678-14.363"/>
                    <path d="m113.53 57.588 0.18731 3.0647 4.2763-5.8131 4.0424-4.1427 3.0068-1.7373 3.3818-1.577-5.0082 9.0714-0.0945 4.1105 1.2757 0.85044 2.5041-1.0394 7.087-10.442 5.4334-3.9688 4.5357 0.85044-3.26 7.276-3.8506 3.8034-2.5986 2.8584-2.4096 0.25986-1.7009-2.8584-0.37797-1.9844"/>
                    <path d="m152.67 33.251-13.33 23.994 1.0691 3.4411 1.7038 0.53454 1.8709-0.83522 1.6704-2.3386 3.4745-6.047"/>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <g transform="translate(0,-159.2)">
            <g>
                <g transform="translate(-3.7042 136.53)" clip-path="url(#clipPath6071)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width="13">
                    <path d="m13.13 29.292-1.1025 4.3765 3.7084 3.8754 7.2163 2.4722 9.0872 0.43431 7.3165-1.6704 3.9756-3.107 1.637-4.009-1.2361-2.6393-2.7061-1.5702-5.3454-0.03341-5.2786 1.6036-4.1427 2.5725-9.889 9.9892-5.2452 10.624-0.23386 3.1404 0.96885 3.9422 2.4388 1.4032 3.2072 0.06682 4.3765-1.9043 5.6795-4.8777 4.8777-5.4122 6.1472-7.7508"/>
                    <path d="m30.864 49.809-0.2008 5.3153-0.33073 4.6302 2.2679 1.7481 2.7876-0.47247 2.9293-2.9766 4.394-6.9926 1.63-0.47247 3.449-3.7089 1.9218-2.7204 3.0736-6.1472 0.55124-3.0235-0.48442-1.0691-1.6871 0.21716-1.637 2.4054-4.861 9.605-2.4388 7.4334-0.29685 4.0478 1.4174 1.4174 1.7245 0.04725 1.7718-0.77958 1.3702-1.441 4.7011-8.2919 10.092-15.58"/>
                    <path d="m52.786 48.352-1.2695 9.1039 1.5895 1.4717 2.1734 0.02363 4.7247-3.2364 2.3369-6.277-0.53454-3.3075-2.0045-1.1693-2.1382 0.33409"/>
                    <path d="m60.937 53.246 8.3856-0.90204 4.1093-2.3052 1.8041-3.2406-0.84593-1.7261h-2.5277l-1.9371 1.63-2.7403 3.2246-1.5119 4.3467 0.18899 3.3545 1.2724 1.4646 2.088 0.16704 2.4889-0.95215 1.7874-1.8041 2.2851-3.7891 5.1972-12.379"/>
                    <path d="m78.41 46.632 4.1093 0.35079 1.0133 0.58244-3.0238 6.7563-0.42522 3.8743 1.2757 0.94494 1.5119-0.75595 6.6974-7.9275 3.842-4.4935 2.2384-3.9422 1.9711-4.3097-0.20045-2.7395-0.83522-0.10023-2.5391 1.6704-2.94 6.3811-2.6727 7.1495-1.5702 5.7129 0.7684 2.6393 1.9711 0.50113 2.4388-1.1693 2.6393-4.0425 1.6036-3.2406"/>
                    <path d="m85.894 43.792 12.395 0.13364"/>
                </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
```

В редакторе картинка выглядит так:

[image]

Comment: а если width и height убрать или сделать не в дюймах?

Comment: Не помогло, убрал ширину и высоту

Comment: мда, проблема глубже, если с элементов убрать clip-path то они отображаются, соответственно сам clip-path сдвинут transform-ом, похоже именно это браузеру и не нравится(смотрел в хроме) https://i.imgur.com/0w7ZuF8.png https://i.imgur.com/jxr5tBT.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Примеры анимации букв

- Анимация вертикального появления букв.

Реализует анимацию вертикальное движение маски

```
<mask id="msk1">
      <rect  y="-50" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" >
       <animate attributeName="y" values="-50;0;-50" dur="4s" fill="freeze" />
       </rect>
     </mask>
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.8" height="101.6" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" >
   
   <defs>
     <mask id="msk1">
   <rect  y="-50" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" >
    <!-- Маска движется вниз открывая буквы -->
    <animate
       attributeName="y"
       values="-50;0;-50"
       dur="4s"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
  </mask>
   </defs>
   
   <!-- Рамка вокруг надписи -->
   
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="279" height="50" fill="none" stroke="#BB00BB" stroke-width="10" />
   
   <g mask="url(#msk1)" transform="translate(10,0)"   > 
     <g fill="dodgerblue"  >
      <!-- Буква G -->
    <path id="G" d="m24.9 29.9q0.4 0 0.4 0.5 0 0.3-0.2 0.5-0.2 0.3-0.5 0.3 0-0.3-0.3-0.7l-3.2 3.3q-3.5 3.7-5.1 5-3.5 2.8-6.2 2.8-2 0-2-1.6 0-2.7 5.3-6.4 5.3-3.7 9.9-4.1l4.5-5q-8.6 6.5-12.3 6.5-1.5 0-2.5-1-1-1-1-2.5 0-3.7 4.5-8.1 4-3.9 9.7-6.8 5.7-2.9 9.3-2.9 2.8 0 2.8 2.2 0 2.4-3 4.8-2.9 2.4-4.6 2.4-1 0-1-1.2 0-1.3 1.7-3 1.2-1.2 2.8-2.3 1.7-1.1 2-1.1 0.3 0 0.3 0.2 0 0.2-1.5 1.1-1.2 0.8-2.6 2.1-1.8 1.7-1.8 2.5 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.3 0 3.9-2.3 2.7-2.3 2.7-3.7 0-1.2-1.7-1.2-3 0-8.4 3.1-5.5 3.1-9.5 7-4.5 4.4-4.5 7.3 0 1.5 1.8 1.5 2.9 0 9.1-4 4.9-3.1 8.4-6.2 0.8-0.7 1-0.7 0.3 0 0.3 0.6 0 0.8-0.8 1.7zm-2.7 0.6q-4.5 0.5-9.2 4.1-4.7 3.6-4.7 5.5 0 0.9 1.3 0.9 1.1 0 2.8-1.1 1.6-1.1 6.8-6.5zM41.3 20.2"/>
   <!-- Буква i -->
    <path id="i" d="m41.3 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
       <!-- Буква l -->
 <path id="l" d="m43.7 26.9-3.9 2.9q-3.1 2.1-4.6 2.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.6-0.4 0.7-0.1 1.5-0.6 1-0.5 3.5-2.4 1.8-1.3 3.8-2.9 2.3-3.5 6.4-7.6 4.5-4.5 6.1-4.5 0.7 0 0.7 0.8 0 2-4.6 6.3-2.9 2.7-6.4 5.3-0.8 0.6-2 2.5-1.2 2-1.2 2.8 0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.8 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.3 0-1.3 1.2-3.8zm13.2-13q-0.6 0-4.8 4.8-4 4.6-5.1 6.3 10.2-8.3 10.2-10.8 0-0.2-0.3-0.2z"/>
    
 <path id="b" d="m56 24q0.8-0.6 1.6-0.6 0.7 0 1.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.2 0 2-2.2 4.4-2.3 2.4-4.2 2.4-1.9 0-1.9-2 0-1 0.9-2.9-2.4 2.2-3.4 2.9-2.6 2-4.1 2-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.6-0.3 4.3-2.5 3-2.4 5.8-5.8 4.1-5.1 7-7.5 3-2.5 4-2.5 1 0 1 1 0 1.1-2 3.3-1.7 1.9-6.2 4.8-0.6 0.4-1.9 1.2-0.2 0.1-0.5 0.6zm10-9.8q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.7 0-4.3 3.7-2.9 3-4.1 4.5 6.2-3.8 7.9-6.7 0.6-1 0.6-1.3zm-9.5 13.6q1.5-1.8 1.5-2.9 0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.8 0-1.4 0.8-0.6 0.7-0.6 1.5 0 1.1 1.2 1.4zm-0.4 0.5q-1.5-0.6-1.5-1.9 0-0.5 0.3-1.2-3.2 4-3.2 5.4 0 0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5 0 3.7-3z"/>
    
 <path id="e" d="m62.3 29.4q-0.8 0.2-2.9 1.4-1.9 1.1-2.9 1.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1-0.2 2.7-1.2 1.9-1.1 3.1-1.4 0.7-1.7 3-3.6 2.4-2 4.1-2 1.3 0 1.3 1.1 0 1.4-2.6 3-1.9 1.2-4 1.9-0.2 0.5-0.2 1 0 0.8 0.6 1.1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.1 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.4-1.9 0.4-2 0-2-1.8 0-0.4 0.1-0.9zm2.1-0.9q1.4-0.7 3-1.9 2.1-1.6 2.1-2.5 0-0.4-0.3-0.4-1 0-2.8 1.9-1.6 1.7-2 2.9z"/>
   
 <path id="r" d="m74.8 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path  id="t" d="m87.5 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
   </g>  
 <path d="m97.4 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m114 27.2q4.3-3.6 6-3.6 1.1 0 1.1 1 0 0.9-2.5 3.3-2.5 2.4-2.5 2.9 0 0.5 0.6 0.5 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.2 0-1 1.3-2.5 0.6-0.8 2.3-2.4 1.3-1.2 1.3-1.4 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.9 0-3.9 2.4-2.5 2-3.7 3.2-1.5 1.6-1.9 1.6-0.2 0-0.5-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5 0-0.4 2.2-2.9l2.6-3-4 3.3-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.5 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 0.6-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.1-0.5 4.7-3.3 3.2-2.6 4.5-3.9 0.2-0.2 0.7-0.6 0.3-0.1 0.5-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.4 0 0.3-2.5 3.6z"/>
    
 <path d="m123.4 28.2-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.4 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1.2-0.3 2.2-0.9 1.5-0.9 4.2-3.2 2.7-2.3 4.1-3.2 1-0.6 1.9-0.6 1.4 0 1.5 1.2 2.3-3 5.3-6.3 4.6-5.2 5.5-5.2 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.5-1.3 1.8-2.4 2.5-7 7.9-5.7 6.7-5.7 7.6 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-0.8 1-2.5-3.1 3.3-4.4 3.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.3 0-0.7 0.7-2.2zm1 2.7q0.9 0 3.5-2.7 2.6-2.7 2.6-3.6 0-0.5-0.4-0.5-1.1 0-3.6 2.6-2.5 2.6-2.5 3.8 0 0.3 0.3 0.3z"/>

  <g fill="crimson"> 
 <path d="m151.3 19q0.2 0 0.2 0.2 0 0.6-2.1 2.2-2.1 1.5-3 1.5-1.2 0-1.2-1.2 0-1.7 3-4.6 2.8-2.7 6.3-4.8 3.7-2.2 5.4-2.2 1.2 0 1.2 1.1 0 0.7-0.8 1.9-0.6 0.8-3.1 3.6-9.1 10-9.1 13.8 0 1.4 1.2 1.4 2.4 0 8.2-5.1 5.8-5.1 9.2-9.8 3.5-4.7 3.5-6 0-0.4-0.5-0.4-1.2 0-4.4 3.2-3.2 3.2-3.2 4.2l0 0.4q0 0.2-0.2 0.2-0.2 0-0.3-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5 0-0.7 1.8-3 1.4-1.7 3.1-3.1 2.3-1.9 3.7-1.9 1.2 0 1.2 1.2 0 2.3-4 7.6-3.2 4.2-8.1 8.5-6.3 5.5-9.8 5.5-1.2 0-1.9-1-0.6-0.9-0.6-2.2 0-2.9 3.4-7.4 2.1-2.7 6.4-7 3.4-3.4 3.4-3.8 0-0.3-0.4-0.3-1.8 0-7.6 4.7-5.9 4.7-5.9 6.3 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.8 0 2.8-1.5 2-1.5 2.1-1.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m173.5 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m174.6 27.6-3.3 2.6q-2.5 1.8-3.9 1.8-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.5-0.3 3.9-2.2l4.3-3.5q3.6-2.9 5.5-2.9 1 0 1 0.8 0.3 0 0.3 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.3-0.3 1.1-1.2 2.2-1 1.3-2 1.3-0.6 0-0.6-0.5 0-0.7 1.2-1.9 1.1-1 1.9-1.4l0-0.2q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-1 0-3.7 2.8-2.7 2.8-2.7 3.9 0 0.7 0.6 1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.2 0.6 0.1 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-2.4 0-2.4-2.2 0-0.8 0.6-2.2zm7-3q-0.5 0.2-1.3 1-0.9 0.9-0.9 1.2l0.1 0.1q0.4 0 1.2-1 0.6-0.8 0.9-1.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m189.8 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
    
 <path d="m192.8 27.8-3.2 2.5q-2.5 1.7-3.7 1.7-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1-0.2 1.6-0.5 1.2-0.6 3.8-2.7l4.1-3.4q1.2-1 1.5-1 0.4 0 0.9 0.4 0.9-0.7 1.6-0.7 1.1 0 1.1 1.1 0 1.7-2.7 4.6-2.8 3-4.5 3-1.6 0-1.6-1.7 0-0.9 1-2.7zm5.3 0q0.6-0.5 1.2-1.5 0.6-1.1 0.6-1.7 0-0.6-0.5-0.6-0.8 0-1.5 1-0.8 1-0.8 1.7 0 0.9 1 1.1zm-1.5-2q-3.2 2.8-3.2 4.5 0 0.8 0.7 0.8 1.2 0 3.7-2.8-1.3-0.3-1.3-1.7 0-0.4 0.1-0.8z"/>
    
 <path d="m206 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path d="m220.6 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m226.8 31.5 1 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3l-1 0-4.4 5.4q-3.9 4.5-5.6 4.5-0.8 0-0.8-1 0-2.3 3.1-5.4 3.1-3 6.3-3.8l3.2-4.2-2.6 2.3q-2.3 1.9-3.2 1.9-1 0-1-1.4 0-1.2 1.1-2.8l1.9-2.4q-1.8 1.6-4.2 3.5-2 1.5-2.6 2-1.9 1.3-3.1 1.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 2-0.5 5.4-3.3l2.7-2.2 1.8-1.6q1.5-1.3 1.7-1.3 0.4 0 0.8 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.7l-2.5 2.9q-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.9 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.9 0 4.6-3.5 2.7-2.5 4.4-4.5 0.4-0.4 0.5-0.4 0.3 0 0.6 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.5 0 0.2-0.2 0.4-2.9 3.1-6.3 7.9zm-2.4 0.9q-3.1 1-5.7 3.7-2.5 2.7-2.5 4.4 0 0.5 0.4 0.5 1.5 0 7.9-8.7z"/>
    
 <path d="m233.5 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

- Анимация горизонтального появления букв

```
<mask id="msk1">
      <rect  x="-279" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" >
       <!-- Маска движется вправо открывая буквы -->
       <animate attributeName="x" values="-279;0;-279" dur="8s" fill="freeze" />
       </rect>
     </mask>
```

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.8" height="101.6" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" >
   
   <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
   <rect  x="-279" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" >
    <!-- Маска движется вправо открывая буквы -->
    <animate
       attributeName="x"
       values="-279;0;-279"
       dur="8s"
       fill="freeze"
       repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </rect>
 </mask>
</defs>
   
   <!-- Рамка вокруг надписи -->
   
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="279" height="50" fill="none" stroke="#BB00BB" stroke-width="10" />
   
   <g mask="url(#msk1)" transform="translate(10,0)"   > 
     <g fill="dodgerblue"  >
      <!-- Буква G -->
    <path id="G" d="m24.9 29.9q0.4 0 0.4 0.5 0 0.3-0.2 0.5-0.2 0.3-0.5 0.3 0-0.3-0.3-0.7l-3.2 3.3q-3.5 3.7-5.1 5-3.5 2.8-6.2 2.8-2 0-2-1.6 0-2.7 5.3-6.4 5.3-3.7 9.9-4.1l4.5-5q-8.6 6.5-12.3 6.5-1.5 0-2.5-1-1-1-1-2.5 0-3.7 4.5-8.1 4-3.9 9.7-6.8 5.7-2.9 9.3-2.9 2.8 0 2.8 2.2 0 2.4-3 4.8-2.9 2.4-4.6 2.4-1 0-1-1.2 0-1.3 1.7-3 1.2-1.2 2.8-2.3 1.7-1.1 2-1.1 0.3 0 0.3 0.2 0 0.2-1.5 1.1-1.2 0.8-2.6 2.1-1.8 1.7-1.8 2.5 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.3 0 3.9-2.3 2.7-2.3 2.7-3.7 0-1.2-1.7-1.2-3 0-8.4 3.1-5.5 3.1-9.5 7-4.5 4.4-4.5 7.3 0 1.5 1.8 1.5 2.9 0 9.1-4 4.9-3.1 8.4-6.2 0.8-0.7 1-0.7 0.3 0 0.3 0.6 0 0.8-0.8 1.7zm-2.7 0.6q-4.5 0.5-9.2 4.1-4.7 3.6-4.7 5.5 0 0.9 1.3 0.9 1.1 0 2.8-1.1 1.6-1.1 6.8-6.5zM41.3 20.2"/>
   <!-- Буква i -->
    <path id="i" d="m41.3 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
       <!-- Буква l -->
 <path id="l" d="m43.7 26.9-3.9 2.9q-3.1 2.1-4.6 2.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.6-0.4 0.7-0.1 1.5-0.6 1-0.5 3.5-2.4 1.8-1.3 3.8-2.9 2.3-3.5 6.4-7.6 4.5-4.5 6.1-4.5 0.7 0 0.7 0.8 0 2-4.6 6.3-2.9 2.7-6.4 5.3-0.8 0.6-2 2.5-1.2 2-1.2 2.8 0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.8 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.3 0-1.3 1.2-3.8zm13.2-13q-0.6 0-4.8 4.8-4 4.6-5.1 6.3 10.2-8.3 10.2-10.8 0-0.2-0.3-0.2z"/>
    
 <path id="b" d="m56 24q0.8-0.6 1.6-0.6 0.7 0 1.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.2 0 2-2.2 4.4-2.3 2.4-4.2 2.4-1.9 0-1.9-2 0-1 0.9-2.9-2.4 2.2-3.4 2.9-2.6 2-4.1 2-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.6-0.3 4.3-2.5 3-2.4 5.8-5.8 4.1-5.1 7-7.5 3-2.5 4-2.5 1 0 1 1 0 1.1-2 3.3-1.7 1.9-6.2 4.8-0.6 0.4-1.9 1.2-0.2 0.1-0.5 0.6zm10-9.8q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.7 0-4.3 3.7-2.9 3-4.1 4.5 6.2-3.8 7.9-6.7 0.6-1 0.6-1.3zm-9.5 13.6q1.5-1.8 1.5-2.9 0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.8 0-1.4 0.8-0.6 0.7-0.6 1.5 0 1.1 1.2 1.4zm-0.4 0.5q-1.5-0.6-1.5-1.9 0-0.5 0.3-1.2-3.2 4-3.2 5.4 0 0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5 0 3.7-3z"/>
    
 <path id="e" d="m62.3 29.4q-0.8 0.2-2.9 1.4-1.9 1.1-2.9 1.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1-0.2 2.7-1.2 1.9-1.1 3.1-1.4 0.7-1.7 3-3.6 2.4-2 4.1-2 1.3 0 1.3 1.1 0 1.4-2.6 3-1.9 1.2-4 1.9-0.2 0.5-0.2 1 0 0.8 0.6 1.1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.1 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.4-1.9 0.4-2 0-2-1.8 0-0.4 0.1-0.9zm2.1-0.9q1.4-0.7 3-1.9 2.1-1.6 2.1-2.5 0-0.4-0.3-0.4-1 0-2.8 1.9-1.6 1.7-2 2.9z"/>
   
 <path id="r" d="m74.8 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path  id="t" d="m87.5 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
   </g>  
 <path d="m97.4 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m114 27.2q4.3-3.6 6-3.6 1.1 0 1.1 1 0 0.9-2.5 3.3-2.5 2.4-2.5 2.9 0 0.5 0.6 0.5 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.2 0-1 1.3-2.5 0.6-0.8 2.3-2.4 1.3-1.2 1.3-1.4 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.9 0-3.9 2.4-2.5 2-3.7 3.2-1.5 1.6-1.9 1.6-0.2 0-0.5-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5 0-0.4 2.2-2.9l2.6-3-4 3.3-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.5 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 0.6-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.1-0.5 4.7-3.3 3.2-2.6 4.5-3.9 0.2-0.2 0.7-0.6 0.3-0.1 0.5-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.4 0 0.3-2.5 3.6z"/>
    
 <path d="m123.4 28.2-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.4 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1.2-0.3 2.2-0.9 1.5-0.9 4.2-3.2 2.7-2.3 4.1-3.2 1-0.6 1.9-0.6 1.4 0 1.5 1.2 2.3-3 5.3-6.3 4.6-5.2 5.5-5.2 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.5-1.3 1.8-2.4 2.5-7 7.9-5.7 6.7-5.7 7.6 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-0.8 1-2.5-3.1 3.3-4.4 3.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.3 0-0.7 0.7-2.2zm1 2.7q0.9 0 3.5-2.7 2.6-2.7 2.6-3.6 0-0.5-0.4-0.5-1.1 0-3.6 2.6-2.5 2.6-2.5 3.8 0 0.3 0.3 0.3z"/>

  <g fill="crimson"> 
 <path d="m151.3 19q0.2 0 0.2 0.2 0 0.6-2.1 2.2-2.1 1.5-3 1.5-1.2 0-1.2-1.2 0-1.7 3-4.6 2.8-2.7 6.3-4.8 3.7-2.2 5.4-2.2 1.2 0 1.2 1.1 0 0.7-0.8 1.9-0.6 0.8-3.1 3.6-9.1 10-9.1 13.8 0 1.4 1.2 1.4 2.4 0 8.2-5.1 5.8-5.1 9.2-9.8 3.5-4.7 3.5-6 0-0.4-0.5-0.4-1.2 0-4.4 3.2-3.2 3.2-3.2 4.2l0 0.4q0 0.2-0.2 0.2-0.2 0-0.3-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5 0-0.7 1.8-3 1.4-1.7 3.1-3.1 2.3-1.9 3.7-1.9 1.2 0 1.2 1.2 0 2.3-4 7.6-3.2 4.2-8.1 8.5-6.3 5.5-9.8 5.5-1.2 0-1.9-1-0.6-0.9-0.6-2.2 0-2.9 3.4-7.4 2.1-2.7 6.4-7 3.4-3.4 3.4-3.8 0-0.3-0.4-0.3-1.8 0-7.6 4.7-5.9 4.7-5.9 6.3 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.8 0 2.8-1.5 2-1.5 2.1-1.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m173.5 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m174.6 27.6-3.3 2.6q-2.5 1.8-3.9 1.8-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.5-0.3 3.9-2.2l4.3-3.5q3.6-2.9 5.5-2.9 1 0 1 0.8 0.3 0 0.3 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.3-0.3 1.1-1.2 2.2-1 1.3-2 1.3-0.6 0-0.6-0.5 0-0.7 1.2-1.9 1.1-1 1.9-1.4l0-0.2q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-1 0-3.7 2.8-2.7 2.8-2.7 3.9 0 0.7 0.6 1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.2 0.6 0.1 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-2.4 0-2.4-2.2 0-0.8 0.6-2.2zm7-3q-0.5 0.2-1.3 1-0.9 0.9-0.9 1.2l0.1 0.1q0.4 0 1.2-1 0.6-0.8 0.9-1.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m189.8 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
    
 <path d="m192.8 27.8-3.2 2.5q-2.5 1.7-3.7 1.7-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1-0.2 1.6-0.5 1.2-0.6 3.8-2.7l4.1-3.4q1.2-1 1.5-1 0.4 0 0.9 0.4 0.9-0.7 1.6-0.7 1.1 0 1.1 1.1 0 1.7-2.7 4.6-2.8 3-4.5 3-1.6 0-1.6-1.7 0-0.9 1-2.7zm5.3 0q0.6-0.5 1.2-1.5 0.6-1.1 0.6-1.7 0-0.6-0.5-0.6-0.8 0-1.5 1-0.8 1-0.8 1.7 0 0.9 1 1.1zm-1.5-2q-3.2 2.8-3.2 4.5 0 0.8 0.7 0.8 1.2 0 3.7-2.8-1.3-0.3-1.3-1.7 0-0.4 0.1-0.8z"/>
    
 <path d="m206 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path d="m220.6 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m226.8 31.5 1 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3l-1 0-4.4 5.4q-3.9 4.5-5.6 4.5-0.8 0-0.8-1 0-2.3 3.1-5.4 3.1-3 6.3-3.8l3.2-4.2-2.6 2.3q-2.3 1.9-3.2 1.9-1 0-1-1.4 0-1.2 1.1-2.8l1.9-2.4q-1.8 1.6-4.2 3.5-2 1.5-2.6 2-1.9 1.3-3.1 1.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 2-0.5 5.4-3.3l2.7-2.2 1.8-1.6q1.5-1.3 1.7-1.3 0.4 0 0.8 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.7l-2.5 2.9q-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.9 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.9 0 4.6-3.5 2.7-2.5 4.4-4.5 0.4-0.4 0.5-0.4 0.3 0 0.6 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.5 0 0.2-0.2 0.4-2.9 3.1-6.3 7.9zm-2.4 0.9q-3.1 1-5.7 3.7-2.5 2.7-2.5 4.4 0 0.5 0.4 0.5 1.5 0 7.9-8.7z"/>
    
 <path d="m233.5 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

- Летающие буквы с горизонтальной парковкой

Анимация достигается изменением позиции X, Y для каждой буквы по отдельности

```
<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
      attributeName="x" 
      attributeType="XML"
    values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
    100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
    200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
    332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
    464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
    332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
    200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
    dur="4s"
    begin="0s"
    repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
      attributeName="y" 
      attributeType="XML"
    values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
    100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
    100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
    500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
    800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
    800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
    500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
        dur="3s"
      begin="0s"
        repeatCount="2" />
```

```html
<style>
 #text1 {

fill:#B2000C;
}
 
</style>
<svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 
 
<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad"
    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="2%" stop-color="steelblue" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(80, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
<text  x="200 " y="500" 
font-size="90" fill="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="4" stroke="#E4E4E4">Gilbert Vict</text> 
<text id="text1" x="200" y="500"
font-size="90">Gilbert Vict</text> 

<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
   attributeName="x" 
   attributeType="XML"
    values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
 100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
 200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
 332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
 464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
 332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
    200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
   attributeName="y" 
   attributeType="XML"
    values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
 100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
 100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
 500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
 800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
 800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
     dur="3s"
   begin="0s"
     repeatCount="2" />


</svg>
```

- Летающие буквы с вертикальной парковкой

```html
<style>
 #text1 {

fill:#B2000C;
}
 
</style>
<svg width="70%" height="70%" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
 
 

<defs>
<linearGradient id="grad"
    x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%"
    gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <stop offset="2%" stop-color="steelblue" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(180, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="45%" stop-color="hsla(80, 100%, 50%, 0)" />
        <stop offset="95%" stop-color="yellowgreen" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs> 
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#grad)" />
<text  x="200 " y="500" 
font-size="90" fill="#E4E4E4" stroke-width="4" stroke="#E4E4E4">Gilbert Vict</text> 
<text id="text1" x="200" y="500"
font-size="90">Gilbert Vict</text> 

<animate xlink:href="#text1" 
 attributeName="x" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596;
 100 600 200 365 700 465 465 563 530 398 431 850 900; 
 200 500 900 950 150 531 300 620 150 266 365 650 900;
 332 233 820 300 800 633 200 670 300 850 800 530 266;
 464 900 900 900 820 670 430 900 530 600 233 365 100;
 332 100 100 100 500 100 800 563 900 700 900 100 100;
    200 233 266 299 332 365 400 431 464 497 530 563 596"
 dur="3s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />
<animate xlink:href="#text1"
 attributeName="y" 
 attributeType="XML"
        values="500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500;
 100 200 850 100 250 175 750 100 750 720 850 500 50; 
 100 600 600 250 200 450 50 200 520 550 300 300 750;
 500 100 650 650 600 150 550 50 150 550 200 550 400; 
 800 300 100 750 150 650 75 350 550 700 755 120 800;
 800 600 300 150 750 350 700 650 200 250 500 650 100;
 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500 500"
 dur="4s"
 begin="0s"
 repeatCount="2" />


</svg>
```

Answer (score 5):

Разбираться вручную в коде, который получен из векторного редактора, очень нелегко. 
Проще и быстрее попробовать сделать самостоятельно нужный текст и это довольно просто.

---

В векторном редакторе можно создать любой текст, с выбором любого шрифта. 
При этом каждая буква будет иметь свой `path`, что даёт богатые возможности для оформления, -  каждой букве можно назначать свой цвет, назначать любую трансформацию: смещения, масштабирования, поворота.
*Также появляется возможность анимировать каждую букву или слово целиком.*

**Техника создания `path` для каждой буквы**

- Загружаете в векторный редактор пустой SVG файл с нужным размером
  холста SVG.

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.8" height="101.6" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" >
```

Выбираете в панели инструментов `Создать и править текстовые объекты` <kbd>F8</kbd>

- Пишите текстовую фразу и подбираете нужный размер и форму начертания
  шрифта.
- Выбираете `Контур / оконтурить обводку` или <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+C</kbd>
- Сохраняете файл. Теперь каждую букву представляет свой `path`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.8" height="101.6" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" >
   <!-- Рамка вокруг надписи -->
   
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="279" height="50" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" />
   
   <g transform="translate(10,0)" > 
      <!-- Буква G -->
    <path id="G" d="m24.9 29.9q0.4 0 0.4 0.5 0 0.3-0.2 0.5-0.2 0.3-0.5 0.3 0-0.3-0.3-0.7l-3.2 3.3q-3.5 3.7-5.1 5-3.5 2.8-6.2 2.8-2 0-2-1.6 0-2.7 5.3-6.4 5.3-3.7 9.9-4.1l4.5-5q-8.6 6.5-12.3 6.5-1.5 0-2.5-1-1-1-1-2.5 0-3.7 4.5-8.1 4-3.9 9.7-6.8 5.7-2.9 9.3-2.9 2.8 0 2.8 2.2 0 2.4-3 4.8-2.9 2.4-4.6 2.4-1 0-1-1.2 0-1.3 1.7-3 1.2-1.2 2.8-2.3 1.7-1.1 2-1.1 0.3 0 0.3 0.2 0 0.2-1.5 1.1-1.2 0.8-2.6 2.1-1.8 1.7-1.8 2.5 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.3 0 3.9-2.3 2.7-2.3 2.7-3.7 0-1.2-1.7-1.2-3 0-8.4 3.1-5.5 3.1-9.5 7-4.5 4.4-4.5 7.3 0 1.5 1.8 1.5 2.9 0 9.1-4 4.9-3.1 8.4-6.2 0.8-0.7 1-0.7 0.3 0 0.3 0.6 0 0.8-0.8 1.7zm-2.7 0.6q-4.5 0.5-9.2 4.1-4.7 3.6-4.7 5.5 0 0.9 1.3 0.9 1.1 0 2.8-1.1 1.6-1.1 6.8-6.5zM41.3 20.2"/>
   <!-- Буква i -->
    <path id="i" d="m41.3 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
       <!-- Буква l -->
 <path id="l" d="m43.7 26.9-3.9 2.9q-3.1 2.1-4.6 2.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.6-0.4 0.7-0.1 1.5-0.6 1-0.5 3.5-2.4 1.8-1.3 3.8-2.9 2.3-3.5 6.4-7.6 4.5-4.5 6.1-4.5 0.7 0 0.7 0.8 0 2-4.6 6.3-2.9 2.7-6.4 5.3-0.8 0.6-2 2.5-1.2 2-1.2 2.8 0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.8 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.3 0-1.3 1.2-3.8zm13.2-13q-0.6 0-4.8 4.8-4 4.6-5.1 6.3 10.2-8.3 10.2-10.8 0-0.2-0.3-0.2z"/>
    
 <path id="b" d="m56 24q0.8-0.6 1.6-0.6 0.7 0 1.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.2 0 2-2.2 4.4-2.3 2.4-4.2 2.4-1.9 0-1.9-2 0-1 0.9-2.9-2.4 2.2-3.4 2.9-2.6 2-4.1 2-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.6-0.3 4.3-2.5 3-2.4 5.8-5.8 4.1-5.1 7-7.5 3-2.5 4-2.5 1 0 1 1 0 1.1-2 3.3-1.7 1.9-6.2 4.8-0.6 0.4-1.9 1.2-0.2 0.1-0.5 0.6zm10-9.8q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.7 0-4.3 3.7-2.9 3-4.1 4.5 6.2-3.8 7.9-6.7 0.6-1 0.6-1.3zm-9.5 13.6q1.5-1.8 1.5-2.9 0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.8 0-1.4 0.8-0.6 0.7-0.6 1.5 0 1.1 1.2 1.4zm-0.4 0.5q-1.5-0.6-1.5-1.9 0-0.5 0.3-1.2-3.2 4-3.2 5.4 0 0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5 0 3.7-3z"/>
    
 <path id="e" d="m62.3 29.4q-0.8 0.2-2.9 1.4-1.9 1.1-2.9 1.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1-0.2 2.7-1.2 1.9-1.1 3.1-1.4 0.7-1.7 3-3.6 2.4-2 4.1-2 1.3 0 1.3 1.1 0 1.4-2.6 3-1.9 1.2-4 1.9-0.2 0.5-0.2 1 0 0.8 0.6 1.1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.1 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.4-1.9 0.4-2 0-2-1.8 0-0.4 0.1-0.9zm2.1-0.9q1.4-0.7 3-1.9 2.1-1.6 2.1-2.5 0-0.4-0.3-0.4-1 0-2.8 1.9-1.6 1.7-2 2.9z"/>
    
 <path id="r" d="m74.8 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path  id="t" d="m87.5 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
    
 <path d="m97.4 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m114 27.2q4.3-3.6 6-3.6 1.1 0 1.1 1 0 0.9-2.5 3.3-2.5 2.4-2.5 2.9 0 0.5 0.6 0.5 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.2 0-1 1.3-2.5 0.6-0.8 2.3-2.4 1.3-1.2 1.3-1.4 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.9 0-3.9 2.4-2.5 2-3.7 3.2-1.5 1.6-1.9 1.6-0.2 0-0.5-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5 0-0.4 2.2-2.9l2.6-3-4 3.3-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.5 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 0.6-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.1-0.5 4.7-3.3 3.2-2.6 4.5-3.9 0.2-0.2 0.7-0.6 0.3-0.1 0.5-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.4 0 0.3-2.5 3.6z"/>
    
 <path d="m123.4 28.2-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.4 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1.2-0.3 2.2-0.9 1.5-0.9 4.2-3.2 2.7-2.3 4.1-3.2 1-0.6 1.9-0.6 1.4 0 1.5 1.2 2.3-3 5.3-6.3 4.6-5.2 5.5-5.2 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.5-1.3 1.8-2.4 2.5-7 7.9-5.7 6.7-5.7 7.6 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-0.8 1-2.5-3.1 3.3-4.4 3.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.3 0-0.7 0.7-2.2zm1 2.7q0.9 0 3.5-2.7 2.6-2.7 2.6-3.6 0-0.5-0.4-0.5-1.1 0-3.6 2.6-2.5 2.6-2.5 3.8 0 0.3 0.3 0.3z"/>
    
 <path d="m151.3 19q0.2 0 0.2 0.2 0 0.6-2.1 2.2-2.1 1.5-3 1.5-1.2 0-1.2-1.2 0-1.7 3-4.6 2.8-2.7 6.3-4.8 3.7-2.2 5.4-2.2 1.2 0 1.2 1.1 0 0.7-0.8 1.9-0.6 0.8-3.1 3.6-9.1 10-9.1 13.8 0 1.4 1.2 1.4 2.4 0 8.2-5.1 5.8-5.1 9.2-9.8 3.5-4.7 3.5-6 0-0.4-0.5-0.4-1.2 0-4.4 3.2-3.2 3.2-3.2 4.2l0 0.4q0 0.2-0.2 0.2-0.2 0-0.3-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5 0-0.7 1.8-3 1.4-1.7 3.1-3.1 2.3-1.9 3.7-1.9 1.2 0 1.2 1.2 0 2.3-4 7.6-3.2 4.2-8.1 8.5-6.3 5.5-9.8 5.5-1.2 0-1.9-1-0.6-0.9-0.6-2.2 0-2.9 3.4-7.4 2.1-2.7 6.4-7 3.4-3.4 3.4-3.8 0-0.3-0.4-0.3-1.8 0-7.6 4.7-5.9 4.7-5.9 6.3 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.8 0 2.8-1.5 2-1.5 2.1-1.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m173.5 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m174.6 27.6-3.3 2.6q-2.5 1.8-3.9 1.8-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.5-0.3 3.9-2.2l4.3-3.5q3.6-2.9 5.5-2.9 1 0 1 0.8 0.3 0 0.3 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.3-0.3 1.1-1.2 2.2-1 1.3-2 1.3-0.6 0-0.6-0.5 0-0.7 1.2-1.9 1.1-1 1.9-1.4l0-0.2q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-1 0-3.7 2.8-2.7 2.8-2.7 3.9 0 0.7 0.6 1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.2 0.6 0.1 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-2.4 0-2.4-2.2 0-0.8 0.6-2.2zm7-3q-0.5 0.2-1.3 1-0.9 0.9-0.9 1.2l0.1 0.1q0.4 0 1.2-1 0.6-0.8 0.9-1.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m189.8 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
    
 <path d="m192.8 27.8-3.2 2.5q-2.5 1.7-3.7 1.7-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1-0.2 1.6-0.5 1.2-0.6 3.8-2.7l4.1-3.4q1.2-1 1.5-1 0.4 0 0.9 0.4 0.9-0.7 1.6-0.7 1.1 0 1.1 1.1 0 1.7-2.7 4.6-2.8 3-4.5 3-1.6 0-1.6-1.7 0-0.9 1-2.7zm5.3 0q0.6-0.5 1.2-1.5 0.6-1.1 0.6-1.7 0-0.6-0.5-0.6-0.8 0-1.5 1-0.8 1-0.8 1.7 0 0.9 1 1.1zm-1.5-2q-3.2 2.8-3.2 4.5 0 0.8 0.7 0.8 1.2 0 3.7-2.8-1.3-0.3-1.3-1.7 0-0.4 0.1-0.8z"/>
    
 <path d="m206 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path d="m220.6 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m226.8 31.5 1 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3l-1 0-4.4 5.4q-3.9 4.5-5.6 4.5-0.8 0-0.8-1 0-2.3 3.1-5.4 3.1-3 6.3-3.8l3.2-4.2-2.6 2.3q-2.3 1.9-3.2 1.9-1 0-1-1.4 0-1.2 1.1-2.8l1.9-2.4q-1.8 1.6-4.2 3.5-2 1.5-2.6 2-1.9 1.3-3.1 1.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 2-0.5 5.4-3.3l2.7-2.2 1.8-1.6q1.5-1.3 1.7-1.3 0.4 0 0.8 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.7l-2.5 2.9q-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.9 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.9 0 4.6-3.5 2.7-2.5 4.4-4.5 0.4-0.4 0.5-0.4 0.3 0 0.6 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.5 0 0.2-0.2 0.4-2.9 3.1-6.3 7.9zm-2.4 0.9q-3.1 1-5.7 3.7-2.5 2.7-2.5 4.4 0 0.5 0.4 0.5 1.5 0 7.9-8.7z"/>
    
 <path d="m233.5 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

**Пример раскраски слов:**

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="558.8" height="101.6" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 279.4 50.8" >
   <!-- Рамка вокруг надписи -->
   
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="279" height="50" fill="none" stroke="#BB00BB" stroke-width="10" />
   
   <g transform="translate(10,0)" > 
     <g fill="dodgerblue">
      <!-- Буква G -->
    <path id="G" d="m24.9 29.9q0.4 0 0.4 0.5 0 0.3-0.2 0.5-0.2 0.3-0.5 0.3 0-0.3-0.3-0.7l-3.2 3.3q-3.5 3.7-5.1 5-3.5 2.8-6.2 2.8-2 0-2-1.6 0-2.7 5.3-6.4 5.3-3.7 9.9-4.1l4.5-5q-8.6 6.5-12.3 6.5-1.5 0-2.5-1-1-1-1-2.5 0-3.7 4.5-8.1 4-3.9 9.7-6.8 5.7-2.9 9.3-2.9 2.8 0 2.8 2.2 0 2.4-3 4.8-2.9 2.4-4.6 2.4-1 0-1-1.2 0-1.3 1.7-3 1.2-1.2 2.8-2.3 1.7-1.1 2-1.1 0.3 0 0.3 0.2 0 0.2-1.5 1.1-1.2 0.8-2.6 2.1-1.8 1.7-1.8 2.5 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 1.3 0 3.9-2.3 2.7-2.3 2.7-3.7 0-1.2-1.7-1.2-3 0-8.4 3.1-5.5 3.1-9.5 7-4.5 4.4-4.5 7.3 0 1.5 1.8 1.5 2.9 0 9.1-4 4.9-3.1 8.4-6.2 0.8-0.7 1-0.7 0.3 0 0.3 0.6 0 0.8-0.8 1.7zm-2.7 0.6q-4.5 0.5-9.2 4.1-4.7 3.6-4.7 5.5 0 0.9 1.3 0.9 1.1 0 2.8-1.1 1.6-1.1 6.8-6.5zM41.3 20.2"/>
   <!-- Буква i -->
    <path id="i" d="m41.3 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
       <!-- Буква l -->
 <path id="l" d="m43.7 26.9-3.9 2.9q-3.1 2.1-4.6 2.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.6-0.4 0.7-0.1 1.5-0.6 1-0.5 3.5-2.4 1.8-1.3 3.8-2.9 2.3-3.5 6.4-7.6 4.5-4.5 6.1-4.5 0.7 0 0.7 0.8 0 2-4.6 6.3-2.9 2.7-6.4 5.3-0.8 0.6-2 2.5-1.2 2-1.2 2.8 0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.8 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.3 0-1.3 1.2-3.8zm13.2-13q-0.6 0-4.8 4.8-4 4.6-5.1 6.3 10.2-8.3 10.2-10.8 0-0.2-0.3-0.2z"/>
    
 <path id="b" d="m56 24q0.8-0.6 1.6-0.6 0.7 0 1.1 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 1.2 0 2-2.2 4.4-2.3 2.4-4.2 2.4-1.9 0-1.9-2 0-1 0.9-2.9-2.4 2.2-3.4 2.9-2.6 2-4.1 2-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.6-0.3 4.3-2.5 3-2.4 5.8-5.8 4.1-5.1 7-7.5 3-2.5 4-2.5 1 0 1 1 0 1.1-2 3.3-1.7 1.9-6.2 4.8-0.6 0.4-1.9 1.2-0.2 0.1-0.5 0.6zm10-9.8q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.7 0-4.3 3.7-2.9 3-4.1 4.5 6.2-3.8 7.9-6.7 0.6-1 0.6-1.3zm-9.5 13.6q1.5-1.8 1.5-2.9 0-0.8-0.7-0.8-0.8 0-1.4 0.8-0.6 0.7-0.6 1.5 0 1.1 1.2 1.4zm-0.4 0.5q-1.5-0.6-1.5-1.9 0-0.5 0.3-1.2-3.2 4-3.2 5.4 0 0.6 0.6 0.6 1.5 0 3.7-3z"/>
    
 <path id="e" d="m62.3 29.4q-0.8 0.2-2.9 1.4-1.9 1.1-2.9 1.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1-0.2 2.7-1.2 1.9-1.1 3.1-1.4 0.7-1.7 3-3.6 2.4-2 4.1-2 1.3 0 1.3 1.1 0 1.4-2.6 3-1.9 1.2-4 1.9-0.2 0.5-0.2 1 0 0.8 0.6 1.1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.1 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.4-1.9 0.4-2 0-2-1.8 0-0.4 0.1-0.9zm2.1-0.9q1.4-0.7 3-1.9 2.1-1.6 2.1-2.5 0-0.4-0.3-0.4-1 0-2.8 1.9-1.6 1.7-2 2.9z"/>
   
 <path id="r" d="m74.8 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path  id="t" d="m87.5 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
   </g>  
 <path d="m97.4 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m114 27.2q4.3-3.6 6-3.6 1.1 0 1.1 1 0 0.9-2.5 3.3-2.5 2.4-2.5 2.9 0 0.5 0.6 0.5 0.6 0 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1.3 0-1.3-1.2 0-1 1.3-2.5 0.6-0.8 2.3-2.4 1.3-1.2 1.3-1.4 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.9 0-3.9 2.4-2.5 2-3.7 3.2-1.5 1.6-1.9 1.6-0.2 0-0.5-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.2-0.5 0-0.4 2.2-2.9l2.6-3-4 3.3-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.5 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 0.6-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.1-0.5 4.7-3.3 3.2-2.6 4.5-3.9 0.2-0.2 0.7-0.6 0.3-0.1 0.5-0.1 0.3 0 0.5 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.4 0 0.3-2.5 3.6z"/>
    
 <path d="m123.4 28.2-3 2.3q-2.2 1.5-3.4 1.5-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1.2-0.3 2.2-0.9 1.5-0.9 4.2-3.2 2.7-2.3 4.1-3.2 1-0.6 1.9-0.6 1.4 0 1.5 1.2 2.3-3 5.3-6.3 4.6-5.2 5.5-5.2 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.5-1.3 1.8-2.4 2.5-7 7.9-5.7 6.7-5.7 7.6 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-0.8 1-2.5-3.1 3.3-4.4 3.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.3 0-0.7 0.7-2.2zm1 2.7q0.9 0 3.5-2.7 2.6-2.7 2.6-3.6 0-0.5-0.4-0.5-1.1 0-3.6 2.6-2.5 2.6-2.5 3.8 0 0.3 0.3 0.3z"/>

  <g fill="crimson"> 
 <path d="m151.3 19q0.2 0 0.2 0.2 0 0.6-2.1 2.2-2.1 1.5-3 1.5-1.2 0-1.2-1.2 0-1.7 3-4.6 2.8-2.7 6.3-4.8 3.7-2.2 5.4-2.2 1.2 0 1.2 1.1 0 0.7-0.8 1.9-0.6 0.8-3.1 3.6-9.1 10-9.1 13.8 0 1.4 1.2 1.4 2.4 0 8.2-5.1 5.8-5.1 9.2-9.8 3.5-4.7 3.5-6 0-0.4-0.5-0.4-1.2 0-4.4 3.2-3.2 3.2-3.2 4.2l0 0.4q0 0.2-0.2 0.2-0.2 0-0.3-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.5 0-0.7 1.8-3 1.4-1.7 3.1-3.1 2.3-1.9 3.7-1.9 1.2 0 1.2 1.2 0 2.3-4 7.6-3.2 4.2-8.1 8.5-6.3 5.5-9.8 5.5-1.2 0-1.9-1-0.6-0.9-0.6-2.2 0-2.9 3.4-7.4 2.1-2.7 6.4-7 3.4-3.4 3.4-3.8 0-0.3-0.4-0.3-1.8 0-7.6 4.7-5.9 4.7-5.9 6.3 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.8 0 2.8-1.5 2-1.5 2.1-1.5z"/>
    
 <path d="m173.5 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m174.6 27.6-3.3 2.6q-2.5 1.8-3.9 1.8-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.4 1.5-0.3 3.9-2.2l4.3-3.5q3.6-2.9 5.5-2.9 1 0 1 0.8 0.3 0 0.3 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.3-0.3 1.1-1.2 2.2-1 1.3-2 1.3-0.6 0-0.6-0.5 0-0.7 1.2-1.9 1.1-1 1.9-1.4l0-0.2q0-0.2-0.2-0.2-1 0-3.7 2.8-2.7 2.8-2.7 3.9 0 0.7 0.6 1 0.3 0.1 1.1 0.2 0.6 0.1 0.6 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-2.4 0-2.4-2.2 0-0.8 0.6-2.2zm7-3q-0.5 0.2-1.3 1-0.9 0.9-0.9 1.2l0.1 0.1q0.4 0 1.2-1 0.6-0.8 0.9-1.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m189.8 21.8-5.6 0.2q-0.5 0-0.5-0.2 0-0.2 0.8-0.3 1.1-0.2 3-0.3 2.2-0.1 3-0.2l2.2-2.7q1.8-2.1 2.2-2.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.6-2.8 4.2 1.6-0.1 2.7-0.1 0.7 0 0.7 0.3 0 0.3-1.7 0.4l-2.4 0.1-3.5 4.4q-3.3 4.3-3.3 5.1 0 0.4 0.5 0.4 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3-1.4 0-1.4-1.1 0-0.9 0.9-2.5l1.4-2.3-4.6 3.6q-2.9 2.3-4.5 2.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.6-0.5 1-0.5 4.7-3.4 2.7-2.1 3.4-2.7 1.2-1.1 2.8-3z"/>
    
 <path d="m192.8 27.8-3.2 2.5q-2.5 1.7-3.7 1.7-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.4 1-0.2 1.6-0.5 1.2-0.6 3.8-2.7l4.1-3.4q1.2-1 1.5-1 0.4 0 0.9 0.4 0.9-0.7 1.6-0.7 1.1 0 1.1 1.1 0 1.7-2.7 4.6-2.8 3-4.5 3-1.6 0-1.6-1.7 0-0.9 1-2.7zm5.3 0q0.6-0.5 1.2-1.5 0.6-1.1 0.6-1.7 0-0.6-0.5-0.6-0.8 0-1.5 1-0.8 1-0.8 1.7 0 0.9 1 1.1zm-1.5-2q-3.2 2.8-3.2 4.5 0 0.8 0.7 0.8 1.2 0 3.7-2.8-1.3-0.3-1.3-1.7 0-0.4 0.1-0.8z"/>
    
 <path d="m206 25.1q-0.1-0.5-0.1-0.6 0-0.4 1-1.3 1-0.9 1.4-0.9 0.4 0 0.4 0.3 0 0.3-0.4 0.9 1.8 0 1.8 1.4 0 1.1-2.3 3.5-2.3 2.4-2.3 2.7 0 0.3 0.3 0.3l0.5 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.9 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1 0-1 1.2-2.5 0.7-1 2.1-2.4 1.2-1.1 1.2-1.2 0-0.2-0.3-0.2-0.2 0-0.9 0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.3-7.3 6.9-9.8 6.9-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 0.5-0.1 1.4-0.5 1.3-0.6 3.8-2.7 2.2-1.9 3.5-3.2z"/>
    
 <path d="m220.6 20.2q-0.7 0-0.7-0.8 0-0.6 0.8-1.2 0.7-0.5 1.4-0.5 0.8 0 0.8 0.9 0 0.6-0.8 1.1-0.7 0.4-1.4 0.4zm-6.9 10.8q0 0.4 0.9 0.4 0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-1 0.3-1.2 0-1.2-1.1 0-1.3 3.5-5.5l-4.3 3.5q-3.8 3.1-5.5 3.1-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 1-0.2 1.8-0.6 1-0.6 4.3-3.2l4.8-4q0.3-0.1 0.8-0.1 0.5 0 0.5 0.6 0 0.7-2.5 3.5-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.4z"/>
    
 <path d="m226.8 31.5 1 0q0.2 0 0.2 0.3 0 0.3-0.7 0.3l-1 0-4.4 5.4q-3.9 4.5-5.6 4.5-0.8 0-0.8-1 0-2.3 3.1-5.4 3.1-3 6.3-3.8l3.2-4.2-2.6 2.3q-2.3 1.9-3.2 1.9-1 0-1-1.4 0-1.2 1.1-2.8l1.9-2.4q-1.8 1.6-4.2 3.5-2 1.5-2.6 2-1.9 1.3-3.1 1.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.3-0.3 2-0.5 5.4-3.3l2.7-2.2 1.8-1.6q1.5-1.3 1.7-1.3 0.4 0 0.8 0.3 0.4 0.3 0.4 0.7l-2.5 2.9q-2.5 2.9-2.5 3.9 0 0.3 0.3 0.3 0.9 0 4.6-3.5 2.7-2.5 4.4-4.5 0.4-0.4 0.5-0.4 0.3 0 0.6 0.2 0.3 0.2 0.3 0.5 0 0.2-0.2 0.4-2.9 3.1-6.3 7.9zm-2.4 0.9q-3.1 1-5.7 3.7-2.5 2.7-2.5 4.4 0 0.5 0.4 0.5 1.5 0 7.9-8.7z"/>
    
 <path d="m233.5 28.7q-4.2 3.3-5.7 3.3-0.2 0-0.2-0.2 0-0.3 0.4-0.3 1.5-0.2 4.1-2.3l2-1.6 3.2-2.6q2.2-1.5 3.8-1.5 1.2 0 1.3 1.2 0.6-0.6 0.8-0.6 0.5 0 0.5 0.4 0 0.5-2.4 3.3-2.4 2.8-2.4 3.3 0 0.3 0.5 0.3 0.5 0 0.5 0.3 0 0.3-1.1 0.3-1 0-1-0.9 0-0.7 0.8-2.1l-1.9 1.6q-1.4 1.1-2.3 1.1-1.3 0-1.3-1.4 0-0.7 0.4-1.7zm7.8-4.6q-0.9 0-3.8 2.8-2.9 2.8-2.9 3.7 0 0.4 0.4 0.4 0.9 0 3.8-2.7 2.9-2.7 2.9-3.6 0-0.5-0.5-0.5z"/>
  </g>
  </g>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Саша и всё таки это паф(path) а патч( patch) то как ты говоришь переводится заплатка/латка или глагол Латать